# Problemas al exportar Excel con Laravel queue y redis

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, queue

Hola buenas tardes a toda la comunidad  necesito ayuda con el siguiente código el cual al exportar un data de más de 68.000 mil **registros** no la exporta aún así se ejecute en segundo plano

```
 ​    ​/** 
 ​     * Entrega los saldos pendientes del mayor 
 ​     * 
 ​     * @param  int $cliente_id [description] 
 ​     * @param  int $cuenta_id  [description] 
 ​     * @param  int $periodo    [description] 
 ​     * @param  int $mes        [description] 
 ​     * @return array             [description] 
 ​     */ 
 ​    ​public​ ​function​ ​pendientes​(​int​ ​$​cliente_id​, ​int​ ​$​cuenta_id​, ​int​ ​$​periodo​, ​int​ ​$​mes​) 
 ​    { 
 ​        ​$​MayorQuery​ = ​new​ ​MayorQuery​(); 
 ​        ​$​detalle_original​ = ​$​MayorQuery​->​Pendientes​(​$​cliente_id​, ​$​cuenta_id​, ​$​periodo​, ​$​mes​); 
  
 ​        ​$​cuenta​ = ​CuentaContabilidad​::​find​(​$​cuenta_id​); 
  
  
 ​        ​if​ (​$​cuenta​->​tratamiento_doc​ == ​'BuscarSII'​) { 
 ​            ​$​detalle​ = ​$​this​->​detallePendientesConciliados​(​$​detalle_original​); 
 ​        } ​else​ { 
 ​            ​$​detalle​ = ​$​detalle_original​; 
 ​        } 
  
  
  
 ​        ​return​ ​$​detalle​; 
 ​    }
```

Esta function entrega los saldos pendientes donde la variable **detalle_original** trae los 68.000 mil registro el problema es cuando esta cuenta verifica la conciliación o los saldos conciliados lo cual genera el siguiente query

```
 ​    ​public​ ​function​ ​detallePendientesConciliados​(​$​mayorData​) 
 ​    { 
 ​        ​$​detalle​ = ​$​mayorData​; 
  
 ​        ​$​docs​ = []; 
 ​        ​$​nc​ = []; ​// Notas de Debito/Credito con detalle de los docs que referencian 
 ​        ​$​nc_borrar_indice​ = []; ​//Indices de NC en detalle 
 ​        ​$​nc_doc_ref_cuadrado​ = []; ​//Notas de credito/debito de documentos no en detalle 0 
 ​        ​$​all_nc_ref​ = []; ​//Todas la NC/ND 
 ​        ​$​all_docs​ = []; ​//Todos los Nr de Docs del Detalle 
  
 ​        ​$​LibroVentaSII​ = ​new​ ​LibroVentaSII​(); 
 ​        ​//dd($detalle); 
 ​        ​//Busco las NC para obtener el documento de referencia 
  
 ​        ​foreach​ (​$​detalle​ ​as​ ​$​k​ => &​$​d​) { 
 ​            ​$​valores​ = [​$​d​->​valor_abono​, ​$​d​->​valor_cargo​]; 
  
 ​            ​$​cliente_id​ = ​$​d​->​cliente_id​; 
  
 ​            ​//Busca el documento en el SII por RUT, Folio y Monto total 
 ​            ​$​doc_sii​ = ​$​LibroVentaSII​::​select​(​'monto_total'​, ​'folio'​, ​'rut'​)->​where​(​'cliente_id'​, ​$​cliente_id​) 
 ​                ->​where​(​'folio'​, ​$​d​->​doc_nro​) 
 ​                ->​where​(​'rut'​, ​$​d​->​rut​) 
 ​                ->​where​( 
 ​                    ​function​ (​$​query​) ​use​ (​$​valores​, ​$​cliente_id​) { 
 ​                        ​foreach​ (​$​valores​ ​as​ ​$​valor​) { 
 ​                            ​if​ (​$​valor​ != ​0​) { 
 ​                                ​$​query​->​orwhere​(​'monto_total'​, ​$​valor​); 
 ​                            } 
 ​                        } 
 ​                    } 
 ​                ) 
 ​                ->​first​(); 
  
 ​            ​if​ (​isset​(​$​doc_sii​)) { 
 ​                ​if​ (​in_array​(​$​doc_sii​->​tipo_doc​, [​61​, ​56​])) { 
 ​                    ​$​nc​[​$​doc_sii​->​rut​][​$​doc_sii​->​folio​][] = (​object​) [ 
 ​                        ​'valor'​ => ​$​doc_sii​->​monto_total​, 
 ​                    ]; 
 ​                } 
 ​            } 
 ​        } 
 ​        ​//Revisamos todas la NC y ND encontradas 
 ​        ​if​ (!​empty​(​$​nc​)) { 
 ​            ​foreach​ (​$​nc​ ​as​ ​$​rut​ => ​$​docs​) { 
  
 ​                ​foreach​ (​$​docs​ ​as​ ​$​nc_nro​ => ​$​doc_refs​) { 
  
 ​                    ​foreach​ (​$​doc_refs​ ​as​ ​$​doc​) { 
  
 ​                        ​$​all_nc_ref​[​$​nc_nro​] = ​$​doc​->​ref_doc​; 
  
 ​                        ​foreach​ (​$​detalle​ ​as​ ​$​i​ => ​$​d​) { 
  
 ​                            ​//Recalcula el saldo del documento origen con el valor de la NC o ND 
 ​                            ​if​ (​$​d​->​rut​ == ​$​rut​ and ​$​doc​->​ref_doc​ == ​$​d​->​doc_nro​) { 
 ​                                ​//                          echo $nc_nro; 
 ​                                ​if​ (​$​doc​->​ref_tipo​ == ​61​) { 
 ​                                    ​$​detalle​[​$​i​]->​valor_abono​ += ​$​doc​->​valor​; 
 ​                                } 
 ​                                ​if​ (​$​doc​->​ref_tipo​ == ​56​) { 
 ​                                    ​$​detalle​[​$​i​]->​valor_cargo​ += ​$​doc​->​valor​; 
 ​                                } 
 ​                                ​$​detalle​[​$​i​]->​saldo​ = (​$​detalle​[​$​i​]->​valor_cargo​ - ​$​detalle​[​$​i​]->​valor_abono​); 
 ​                            } 
 ​                        } 
 ​                    } 
 ​                } 
 ​            } 
  
 ​        } 
  
  
  
 ​        ​return​ ​$​detalle​; 
 ​    }
```

Aquí es donde se genera el estrés en el servidor  por lo que supera los límites de ejecución y la memoria la eleva hasta su límite dejando el servidor sin respiro

Tomen en cuenta que el query se ejecuta de acuerdo a una sola cuenta, cliente, periodo y fecha corte (mes)

Quiere decir que si la fecha corte es febrero periodo 2021  está va hacia atrás comenzando desde el último día de ese mes encontrando así todos los datos de esa cuenta, he probado de muchas formas y aún así el Excel no se genera

Comment: Utilizas demasiados bucles, por supuesto que consumirá bastante memoria y tardará demasiado. Intenta utilizar eager loading o calcula todo desde atributos en los modelos, hay mucho que puedes hacer para hacer rápida la consulta.

Comment: Entiendo pero como hacer para la búsqueda que hace el sistema para conciliar los folios encontrados?

Comment: Dado que para cada nota de crédito o débito tienes la referencia (de otra manera no podrías usar `$d->doc_nro`) por qué tendrías que emparejar tentativamente por algo que no sea `rut+doc_nro+tipo_doc` ? esa tupla ya identifica un DTE único. En caso contrario hay un problema de diseño en el schema.